# ESENTUTL.exe to extract Webcache using VSS

Tags: c#, .net

I have written a simple piece of code to try and copy the WebCacheV01.dat file from the Edge Browser, as the fille is locked I am using the VSS commands to do this.

When I run the command manually, from an elevated prompt, it copies the database without any issue.  When I try to replicate the command using C#, it errors.

> VSS Subsystem Init failed, 0x80042302 Operation terminated with error
>   -2403 (JET_errOSSnapshotNotAllowed, OS Shadow copy not allowed (backup or recovery in progress)) after 0.47 seconds.

I have run the debugging, line by line and the arguments are correct.  I just can't get around the error message.

```
                using (var cmdEsentutl = new Process())
            {
                cmdEsentutl.StartInfo.FileName = "esentutl";
                cmdEsentutl.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                cmdEsentutl.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
                //cmdEsentutl.StartInfo.Arguments = $@"/y /vss {GlobalVariables.edge44HistoryDB}\WebCacheV01.dat /d E:\WebCacheV01.dat";
                cmdEsentutl.StartInfo.Arguments = $@"/y {GlobalVariables.edge44HistoryDB}\WebCacheV01.dat /vssrec V01 . /d F:\WebCacheV01.dat";
                cmdEsentutl.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
                cmdEsentutl.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                cmdEsentutl.Start();
                cmdEsentutl.WaitForExit();
            }
```

Comment: Maybe see if you can glean anything from this documentation? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/volume-shadow-copy-service Otherwise maybe invoke the command line in code to get around the issue temporarily?